# Proving two elements of a set are equal based on a two-sided identity

Tags: group-theory, binary-operations, associativity

Say I have a set **S** w/ an associative binary operation *: **S x S -> S** and a two-sided identity **e**, and let [image: sES]. Let [image: SsubL]<sub>L</sub> and [image: SsubR]<sub>R</sub> be elements of **S** such that [image: Ssib:]<sub>L</sub> * **s = e = s** * [image: SsubR]<sub>R</sub>

How can I prove that [image: Ssib:]<sub>L</sub> = [image: SsubR]<sub>R</sub> ?

Since the left and right identity are equal to **e** which is a two-sided identity, that proves that the left and right are equal just by the definition of a two-sided identity right? Is there some more in-depth proof I'm not seeing here?

Comment: Does this hold for all $s \in S$, or do $\tilde{s}_L$ and $\tilde{s}_R$ depend on $s$? (Note: this was typed as `Does this hold for all $s \in S$, or do $\tilde{s}_L$ and $\tilde{s}_R$ depend on $s$?`)

Comment: I thought they were the same thing. I'll be honest, I don't know what the squiggly line over the s stands for. But I figured since s is an element in S then $\tilde{s}_L$ and $\tilde{s}_R$ are as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\tilde s_R=e*\tilde s_R=(\tilde s_L*s)*\tilde s_R=\tilde s_L*(s*\tilde s_R)=\tilde s_L*e=\tilde s_L\;.$$

Comment: I had something like this but I didn't understand it. Could you elaborate a little bit? Thank you.

Comment: @pfinferno: Would be a lot more efficient if you pointed out which step(s) or aspect(s) you don't understand.

Comment: Well what does the tilde above the s mean? The only place I saw it online was a .pdf that this problem came from and it didn't give a description. Once I know what that is I think it will make sense.

Comment: @pfinferno: I'd suggest that when you use notation in a question that you don't understand, you should point that out -- it would make it easier to understand where your problems lie, and what sort of answer might be helpful. I don't think this tilde is a standard notational convention. I suspect it's being used to mark inverses. In any case $\tilde s_L$ and $\tilde s_R$ are left and right inverses of $s$, respectively, and the statement being proved is that with a two-sided identity left and right inverses are equal.